# what is the role of the bold part in the following sentence:

Tags: meaning

Only get rid of Man, and the produce of our labour would be our own. Almost overnight we could become rich and free. What then must we do? **Why**, work night and day, body and soul, for the overthrow of the human race! That is my message to you, comrades: Rebellion

Comment: Although your quotation seems perfectly clear, it's not at all obvious what you're asking.

In this case, "the bold part in the following sentence" ie, "Why" serves purely for emphasis. Drop it, then explain how the meaning changes, other than in emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rhetorical *why*, used for emphasis.

> **[why](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/why)**
>
> EXCLAMATION
>
> 2. Used to add emphasis to a response.
>    ‘‘You think so?’ ‘Why, yes.’’
>    ‘Why yes, how did you know?’

Comment: What source have you cited?  I'm used to the label "interjection" for this word class, leaving "exclamation" free to describe a type of sentence.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan The source is linked. It's Oxford Living Dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

The first part forms a question in response to the preceding unbolded part. The question, more completely, is "What must we do to get rid of man so we can have the produce of our labor for our own?" The second part of bolded text is a list of things to be done in order to destroy man. In toto the phrase seems to be a circular argument against rebellion.

Comment: "*a circular argument against rebellion*" Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I  think the author is making an argument against Rebellion by proposing that if (violent) rebellion is a person's proposed way to eliminate barriers to happiness and man is the biggest barrier to happiness, then logically you should destroy all men, including yourself.

Comment: LOL. Are you not aware that "the author" is not a man but a pig? The above is a quote from Old Major's speech in George Orwell's Animal Farm.